# How to quickly search for abbreviation in Netbeans Code templates?

Tags: netbeans-7, shortcut, abbreviation, code-templates

When I open Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Templates in  Netbeans 7.1.1, I can see list of saved templates. But when there are too many templates, I have no option to quickly find some particular template, that I wish to edit.  I cannot search fo abbreviation, filter, or even resize the list with Templates. I can just filter shortuts by programming language. 
The only way to find some particular shortcut, is to use scrollbar.

I would like to have some textfield, where I can type abbreviation I am searching for, and then I am able to get directly to editation of this abbreviation. 
IS something like this possible in Netbeans or other enhancement of Code templates management?

Comment: I too an hit by this. Simply searching for a code template that does something I normally type manually, is hard to say the least, and that it's full of ${variables} isn't helping.